# How to pass a replacing regex as a command line argument to a perl script

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a simple perl script to apply a given regex to a filename among other things, and I am having trouble passing a regex into the script as an argument.

What I would like to be able to do is somthing like this:

```
> myscript 's/hi/bye/i' hi.h
bye.h
>
```

I have produced this code

```
#!/utils/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n_args = $#ARGV + 1;
my $regex =  $ARGV[0];
for(my $i=1; $i<$n_args; $i++) {
  my $file = $ARGV[$i];

  $file =~ $regex;
  print "OUTPUT: $file\n";
}
```

I cannot use qr because apparently it cannot be used on replacing regexes (although my source for this is a forum post so I'm happy to be proved wrong).

I would rather avoid passing the two parts in as seperate strings and manually doing the regex in the perl script.

Is it possible to pass the regex as an argument like this, and if so what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's more than one way to do it, I think.

**The Ev<del>i</del>al Way:**

As you basically send in a regex expression, it can be evaluated to get the result. Like this:

```
my @args = ('s/hi/bye/', 'hi.h');
my ($regex, @filenames) = @args;
for my $file (@filenames) {
  eval("\$file =~ $regex");
  print "OUTPUT: $file\n";
}
```

Of course, following this way will open you to some very nasty surprises. For example, consider passing this set of arguments:

```
...
my @args = ('s/hi/bye/; print qq{MINE IS AN EVIL LAUGH!\n}', 'hi.h');
...
```

Yes, it will laugh at you most ev<del>a</del>illy.

**The Safe Way:**

```
my ($regex_expr, @filenames) = @args;
my ($substr, $replace) = $regex_expr =~ m#^s/((?:[^/]|\\/)+)/((?:[^/]|\\/)+)/#;
for my $file (@filenames) {
  $file =~ s/$substr/$replace/;
  print "OUTPUT: $file\n";
}
```

As you can see, we parse the expression given to us into two parts, then use these parts to build a full operator. Obviously, this approach is less flexible, but, of course, it's much more safe.

**The Easiest Way:**

```
my ($search, $replace, @filenames) = @args;
for my $file (@filenames) {
  $file =~ s/$search/$replace/;
  print "OUTPUT: $file\n";
}
```

Yes, that's right - no regex parsing at all! What happens here is we decided to take two arguments - 'search pattern' and 'replacement string' - instead of a single one. Will it make our script less flexible than the previous one? No, as we still had to parse the regex expression more-or-less regularly. But now user clearly understand *all* the data that is given to a command, which is usually quite an improvement. )

*@args in both examples corresponds to @ARGV array.*

Comment: I'd give you another +1 for the line `my ($regex_expr, @filenames) = @args;` if i could. Thats going to make my life a lot easier :-)

Comment: This only works with the default `/` delimiter, though. Also, it breakes if `\/` is present in the substitution.

Comment: @choroba Applied a fix, but it actually depends on how these should be processed (literally or quotemeta-ed). As for different delimiters... well, I think it's easier then to use _two_ arguments (one for substr, another for replace) instead of single one.

Comment: Just to add one further complication: will this correctly handle `$/` (the input line separator, usually `\n`)?  I suspect not, at least in part because I suspect Perl's actual rules for parsing `$/` inside a regex are along the lines of "nobody really knows, so, um, don't do that".  :-/

Comment: Parsing the regex seems like a fragile solution. Why not just pass the strings as-is to the script instead of trying to hack up a regex?

Comment: @TLP Updated my answer, as you're quite right. ) I've discussed this in the above comments, but then again, these are not the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `s/a/b/i` is an operator, not simply a regular expression, so you need to use `eval` if you want it to be interpreted properly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $regex = shift;
my $sub = eval "sub { \$_[0] =~ $regex; }";

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    &$sub($file);
    print "OUTPUT: $file\n";
}
```

The trick here is that I'm substituting this "bit of code" into a string to produce Perl code that defines an anonymous subroutine `$_[0] =~ s/a/b/i;` (or whatever code you pass it), then using `eval` to compile that code and give me a code reference I can call from within the loop.

```
$ test.pl 's/foo/bar/' foo nicefood
OUTPUT: bar
OUTPUT: nicebard

$ test.pl 'tr/o/e/' foo nicefood
OUTPUT: fee
OUTPUT: nicefeed
```

This is more efficient than putting an `eval "\$file =~ $regex;"` inside the loop as then it'll get compiled and eval-ed at every iteration rather than just once up-front.

A word of warning about `eval` - as raina77ow's answer explains, you should avoid `eval` unless you're 100% sure you are always getting your input from a trusted source...

Comment: +1 for using more efficient approach to `eval`. ) Have to say, though, I consider this approach inferior to parsing the given expression.

Comment: In this example, yes, I agree with you, your "safe approach" (albeit with a more complex parsing approach that can handle `\/` etc.) is definitely the better way to go.

Answer (score 2):

`s/a/b/i` is not a regex. It is a regex plus substitution. Unless you use the string [eval](http://p3rl.org/eval), make this work might be pretty tough (consider `s{a}<b>e` and so on).

Comment: I don't understand your example to consider `s{a}<b>e`. I have attempted to use eval already, I wasn't able to make changes to my $file scalar as you might expect. Could you give a small example to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that you are trying to pass a perl operator when all you really need to pass is the arguments:

```
myscript hi bye hi.h
```

In the script:

```
my ($find, $replace, @files) = @ARGV;
...
$file =~ s/$find/$replace/i;
```

Your code is a bit clunky. This is all you need:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($find, $replace, @files) = @ARGV;
for my $file (@files) {
    $file =~ s/$find/$replace/i;
    print "$file\n";
}
```

Note that this way allows you to use meta characters in the regex, such as `\w{2}foo?`. This can be both a good thing and a bad thing. To make all characters intepreted literally (disable meta characters), you can use `\Q ... \E` like so:

```
... s/\Q$find\E/$replace/i;
```