# How to pass a replacing regex with a backreference as a command line argument to a Perl script

Tags: regex, perl, argument-passing, backreference

[Previous post related:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423337) How to pass a replacing regex as a command line argument to Perl

After reading the above I wrote a very similar script, but I can't get it to interpolate as I intend when I use backreferences such as `$1`. It could be that I'm not using the correct single/double quotes or some combination thereof, but I've been racking my brain for hours.

When I call the program as such it works just fine

```
perl edit.pl "(BUILD_NUMBER)=.*" "BUILD_NUMBER=1.2.3.4" env.properties
1: <-- BUILD_NUMBER=0.0
1: --> BUILD_NUMBER=1.2.3.4
```

When the program is called including backreferences it fails:

```
perl edit.pl "(BUILD_NUMBER)=.*" "$1=1.2.3.4" env.properties
1: <-- BUILD_NUMBER=0.0
1: --> =1.2.3.4
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($searchString, $replaceString, $fileName)  = @ARGV;
my $occurences = 0;
my @newlines=();
my $line="";

open (READ, "$fileName")  || die "File not found";
while ( <READ> ){
    if ($_ =~ $searchString){
        print "$.: <-- $_";
        $_ =~ s/$searchString/$replaceString/;
        print "$.: --> $_","\n";
        $occurences++;
    }
    push(@newlines,$_);
}
print "Lines: $., Changes: $occurences";
close(READ);

open(WRITE, ">$fileName") || die "File not found";
print WRITE @newlines;
close(WRITE);
```

Comment: Please don't use HTML in your post. Use the Markup instead, using the code formatting for code, and not blockquote.

Comment: The problem is that `$1` is (probably) interpolated by your shell and replaced with an empty string. You could try using single quotes instead. Or you could leave it out, and use a lookbehind assertion in the first argument instead: `"(?<=BUILD_NUMBER=)"`.

Comment: Replace `perl` with `echo` in your command line so that you can see what is *really* being passed to the program.

Comment: You know that your entire script can be replaced with a one-liner by the way? `perl -pi -e's/^BUILD_NUMBER=\K.*/1.2.3.4/' env.properties` -- though you won't get confirmation of what changed unless you add that part. You should be aware that using the `-i` switch causes irreversible changes to the file. But you are already doing something equivalent, so I guess you know that.

Comment: I tried single quotes and that resulted in "$1=1.2.3.4". I tried dereferencing with "\" multiple "$" and I'm still not finding the right combination to get me the desired result.

Comment: TLP, I agree it's an easy one liner if I didn't have the requirement of an audit trail of what changes each run of the script makes.

Comment: Yes, it is treating `$1` as a string of course. In that case you'd need to eval the string, but that is horrible. Just use the lookbehind assertion instead, or `\K` if you have the Perl version for it (5.10+ I think).

Comment: As it turns out when I run this on a windows command prompt that doesn't interpolate $1, it still fails.  Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's a really nasty way to do things (you're esentially treating Perl code as data) but you can get it to work by changing

```
$_ =~ s/$searchString/$replaceString/;
```

to either

```
s/$searchString/$replaceString/ee;
```

or

```
eval "s/$searchString/$replaceString/";
```

The usual caveats apply to using `eval` on externally-sourced data.

Much better would be to avoid backreferences altogether, and use the command line

```
perl edit.pl 'BUILD_NUMBER=\K.*' '1.2.3.4' env.properties
```

or, if you are using a very old version of Perl

```
perl edit.pl '(?<=BUILD_NUMBER=).*' '1.2.3.4' env.properties
```